# How to use AsyncTask with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: android, threadpool, android-asynctask

I am a little confused on ThreadPoolExecutor.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a list-view which is populated with an image icon to the left and a short description to its right.  I have all of the text already defined statically, however i want to get the icons from the the web.  I already know how to get the image from a url, however I dont want to spawn 'n' amount of threads per icon to grab the icon image.  So i read up on threadpoolexecutor for asynctask and I am not sure how to go about it. can you guys give me a head start? do I have to create a threadpoolexecutor and use asynctasks within it?

My list is like this.. without the icons.

```
___________________________
[icon][a short description]
____________________________
[icon][a short description]
_____________________________
[icon][a short description]
_____________________________
[icon][a short description]
____________________________
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend just using AsyncTask and not worry about the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which requires HoneyComb anyway. AsyncTask has a pool of threads that will be reused for all of your list items. It won't create a bunch of threads per icon.

Just keep in mind that your tasks will be running in parallel on Android 2.x and to keep track of any synchronization issues your code might have.

Comment: When i do a Log.d(TAG, "Created") in my async task it shows that 'n' amount of threads are created.  So what you are saying that even though they are created, Async has an internal way of controlling it's thread pool?

Comment: You need to create a new instance of AsyncTask for every task that you have and execute it. You shouldn't reuse those instances. AsyncTask manages a thread pool and all the tasks share that pool.

Comment: @StevePrentice As per the documentation [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is available since API level 1. I feel it's the best solution.

Comment: @Dheeraj, AsyncTask wasn't available until api level 3 and AsyncTask.exexcuteOnExecutor wasn't available until api level 11 (honeycomb).

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use method [executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) to start it with your own executor.

There seems to be number of gotchas, so read carefully the entire page for `AsyncTask`.

So yes, you can create your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` and use it with `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thanks ill look further into it!  Looks pretty annoying to use.. lol

Comment: However, that's not available for API levels below 11